# IBM MobileFirst Platform is not triggering Remote disable message on iOS for Hybrid app

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

We have a hybrid application that doesn't show the remote disable message once we change the state from "Active" to "Access Disabled" even though the app is actually getting disabled as we can't use it anymore.

worklight.properties:

```
wl.remoteDisable.cache.enabled=true
wl.remoteDisable.cache.refreshIntervalInSeconds=1
```

initOption.js (I have added console.log to see what is the error in between):

```
onErrorRemoteDisableDenial : function (message, downloadLink) {
        console.log("onErrorRemoteDisableDenial ......... Triggered");
            WL.SimpleDialog.show(
                    appStoreUpdateTitle,
                    message,
                    [{text: notNowButton, handler: function() {WL.App.close();}},
                     {text: downloadNewVersionBtn, handler: function() {WL.App.openURL(downloadLink, "_blank");}}]
            );
                console.log("onErrorRemoteDisableDenial ......... Endded");
        },
```

console.log (from xCode):

```
2017-03-28 10:51:57.312 GRSMobile[73598:5607189] onErrorRemoteDisableDenial ......... Triggered
2017-03-28 10:51:57.315 GRSMobile[73598:5607189] Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7f9e29e2c000> on <CDVViewController: 0x7f9e29dd0290> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
2017-03-28 10:51:57.315 GRSMobile[73598:5607189] onErrorRemoteDisableDenial ......... Endded
```

The same code works on Android but not iOS.

IBM MobileFirst Platform Version: 7.1.0.00.20161118-2214

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior seems similar to [APAR PI74295](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI74295), which is fixed in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 builds dated 20170109-1751 (and later).  I suspect the cause is the same.

I would recommend to obtain a more recent iFix build and apply it, and use that to build your application and confirm if this issue is resolved.

Comment: Thank you. I have applied the iFix, recompiled all my app artifacts (WAR, WLAPP, IPA) and I can now see the access disabled message. iFix applied is (7.1.0.00.20170301-1645)