# MobileFirst 7.1 access disabled message/ Active notify message and Direct update message disappear immediately after the application is loaded

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

We have two applications that We were unable to show direct update message, active notify or access disable message.

Referring to the question I raised previously, we have applied the iFix and rebuilt our application (WAR, WLAPP)with MFP 7.1 version 7.1.0.00.20170301-1645.

[IBM MobileFirst Platform is not triggering Remote disable message on iOS for Hybrid app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073148/ibm-mobilefirst-platform-is-not-triggering-remote-disable-message-on-ios-for-hyb)

However,Once the application is launched, we can see the Active notify message, Access disable message or direct update message for about one sec then the messages disappear immediately once the splash screen is gone without any interaction from the user and it only happening on iOS devices (iPhone and iPad), I'm unable to identify what could be the root cause and if this is a known issue.

[image]

[image]

Access Disable code:

```
onErrorRemoteDisableDenial: function(message, downloadLink) {

            WL.SimpleDialog.show(
                appStoreUpdateTitle,
                message, [{ text: notNowButton, handler: function() { WL.App.close(); } },
                    { text: downloadNewVersionBtn, handler: function() { WL.App.openURL(downloadLink, "_blank"); } }
                ]
            );
```

Direct Update Code:

```
wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.handleDirectUpdate = function(directUpdateData, directUpdateContext) {

        var downloadSizeInMB = (directUpdateData.downloadSize / 1048576).toFixed(1).replace("." , WL.App.getDecimalSeparator());
        //var directUpdateMsg = WL.Utils.formatString(WL.ClientMessages.directUpdateNotificationMessage, downloadSizeInMB) + extraMessage;

        var notNowButton="Not Now" ;
        var directUpdateTitle = "Application requires update" ;
        var directUpdateButton = "Update";
        var directUpdateMessage= "A new software update for Manulife GRS Mobile is now available. The file size is "+ downloadSizeInMB + " MB. Please update your software now to continue using the application.";



    if  (getLanguage() == "fr" ) {
              notNowButton = "Pas maintenant";
              directUpdateTitle = "L’application nécessite une mise à jour";
               directUpdateButton = "Mettre à jour";
              directUpdateMessage = "Une nouvelle version de l’application Services mobiles GRS Manuvie est maintenant à votre disposition. La taille du fichier est de "+ downloadSizeInMB +" Mo. Veuillez effectuer la mise à jour dès maintenant pour pouvoir continuer à utiliser l’application.";

       }


         WL.SimpleDialog.show(directUpdateTitle, directUpdateMessage,
               [{
                   text : directUpdateButton,
                   handler : function() {
                       directUpdateContext.start(); // if you need to remove the background running just remove the "directUpdateCustomListener"
                   }
               },
               {
                   text : notNowButton,
                   handler : function() {
                       wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.submitFailure();
                   }
               },

               ]
           );
       };
```

Active Notify has no code in MFP as I couldn't find the place to customize it.

Comment: Have you customized direct update , active notifying/remote disable features to show your own custom dialog?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my question.